# Error in Wikipedia pseudocode for Prim's Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, prims-algorithm

So I'm looking at [the Wikipedia entry on Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm):

```
1. Associate with each vertex v of the graph a number C[v] (the cheapest cost of a connection to v) and an edge E[v] (the edge providing that cheapest connection). To initialize these values, set all values of C[v] to +∞ (or to any number larger than the maximum edge weight) and set each E[v] to a special flag value indicating that there is no edge connecting v to earlier vertices.
2. Initialize an empty forest F and a set Q of vertices that have not yet been included in F (initially, all vertices).
3. Repeat the following steps until Q is empty:
      a. Find and remove a vertex v from Q having the minimum possible value of C[v]
      b. Add v to F
      c. Loop over the edges vw connecting v to other vertices w. For each such edge, if w still belongs to Q and vw has smaller weight than C[w], perform the following steps:
            i. Set C[w] to the cost of edge vw
            ii. Set E[w] to point to edge vw.
4. Return F
```

My question is about step 3.b ("Add v to F").  **Is step 3b an error?** "v" is a vertex and the Minimum Spanning Tree is a set of edges (not a set of vertices).

It seems like step 3b ought to read "Add E[v] to F" instead.

Comment: You need to start with the [definition of a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)). Trees contain vertices and edges.

Comment: Where are the edges added to F?

Comment: Step 1 in the algorithm: *"Associate with each vertex v of the graph [...] an edge E[v] (the edge providing that cheapest connection)."* The number of edges in the spanning tree is V-1. The first vertex doesn't have any edge associated with it. Every other vertex has information about the edge that connected it to the tree.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was reading that as "arrays C and E contain data and we as humans know that the data corresponds to the cost & minimum edge to get to vertex v".  So the idea is that we're returning F, the set of vertices, and each vertex keeps a connection to the C and E arrays (after they're returned from the function/algorithm)?

Comment: Ah, I see. You're thinking that `C` and `E` are literally arrays, because you've seen square brackets used for arrays in real code. Pseudocode is not real code, and in pseudocode, syntax means what the author says it means. The author states that C[v] means *"(the cheapest cost of a connection to v)"*, and E[v] means *"(the edge providing that cheapest connection)"*. That's all C[v] and E[v] mean in that pseudocode. There's no implication that E is an array.

Comment: That is exactly the source of my confusion.  Thank you for clarifying - that helps a ton!

Comment: The Wikipedia page in question [has since been edited](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Prim%27s_algorithm&diff=1157183813&oldid=1153220130) to change the line `Return F` into `Return F, which specifically includes the corresponding edges in E`. The reason `v` must be added to `F` in step 2 is because `F` is initially an "empty forest", so it would have no vertices unless some are added.

Answer (score 0):

Step 3b adds vertex v to F.  Steps ci and cii then add edges to F

Comment: Doesn't that just update the C[] and E[] arrays?  Neither of those are part of F, are they?  And at the end of the method we return F, not C[] or E[]